# Problem UIScrollView pagingenabled in IOS 3.1.3

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, paging, ios3.0

I have set paging property of scroll view to 'scrollview.pagingEnabled = YES'. When tested  it seems to be working in IOS 4 and above but it is not working on iOS 3.1.3. Can any one help me with this?

Comment: I think you can only publish apps targeted to iOS > 3.2 on the App Store, so it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "not working"?

Comment: When i swipes to another page content is not moving like a page in IOS 3.1.3.

Comment: I have the exact same problem with 3.1.3, runs great on iOS 4+

Comment: Ican Zilb, many production apps I work on have a 5% or more 3.x user base so until that number goes down many iOS shops will need to continue supporting 3.x users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to start with pagingEnabled and bounces both set to YES

and then you can set set contentSize=CGSizeMake(width, height);

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same problem! I found that in iOS < 3.2 pagingEnabled=YES only works if bounces=YES which is a bummer. I didn't want bounces to be enabled so in my app I check if iOS < 3.2 and then only enable bounces for those older iOS version.

Answer (score 0):

Keep Paging Enabled checked for ScrollView in interface builder.